# How to make an infinite table of buttons HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website, which needs to have a infinite table (-Infinity to +Infinity in X and Y). The user should be able to scroll both ways, and if possible, zoom in and out (show more rows and columns on the same size viewport). I need to have click detection on all the cells, so would there be any way to create a table like this with buttons in each cell, using HMTL/CSS/JS?

The best example I could find online was https://shapez.io/, however the source (https://github.com/tobspr/shapez.io)  is pretty large, and finding all the camera/rendering/movement seems like a large hassle that might not be necessary.

My current code doesn't work (The loops never finish)

```
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '100%';
  tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
  var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
  for (var i = -Infinity; i < Infinity; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = -Infinity; j < Infinity; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0020'))
        i == 1 && j == 1 ? td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2') : null;
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  body.appendChild(tbl)
}
tableCreate();
```

Comment: look into lazy loading, basically you only render what the user wants to see, so at first a certain size, then add on each time he scrolls to the end of the table on either size and only load that side. i can't give you a working example because never really worked with lazy loading this way but google it and you'll find some working example. and of course your code would do an infinite loop since you want an infinite table

Comment: Yeah those are infinite loops all right. More details about your app would be useful. Are you making a game? Does the world need to be stateful, i.e. user scrolls in one direction a million units, then scrolls back, must they see exactly the same thing? Is there a threshold at which point you can randomize? Is content procedurally generated? How/where is data coming from/going to (a server?)? There are a lot of factors so this seems pretty open-ended.

Comment: you can't enumerate an infinite set, nor can you render an infinitely large table.  What you have to do is _simulate_ an infinitely large (or perhaps "unlimited"  would be a better description than "infinite") table by rendering only the parts relevant at a given time, like @chawkichalladia suggests.